# HOW to convert a Stringvar into a date

Tags: python, string, date, tkinter

```
def btw_show():
    date_s = datetime.date.today()
    date_w = StringVar()
    date_w.set(date_s)

    date_input = Entry(root, width=16, font=("aial", 30), textvariable=date_w, background='black', foreground='cyan')
    date_input.pack(anchor='se')
    btn.destroy()

    date_w.get()
```

`date_w` how to convert it into a `date`?

**btw:** I import everything I need.

Comment: How is your code acting different from expected?

Comment: Does it mean that you want to convert the content of `StringVar` to `datetime.date`?

Comment: what did you try? `datetime` has `strptime` to `string parse time`

Comment: better show minimal working code and better describe problem because I see in code totally different problem - you try to get `date_w` in wrong moment. You try to get time directly after displayin `Entry` but GUI doesn't work like `input()` - it doesn't wait for your data but it runs directly `date_w.get()` and you try to get value before you change text in `Entry`.  You would need other button to run other function after you put text in `Entry` - and this function will get correct value.

Answer (score 0):

`datetime` has function `strptime` (string parse time) to convert string to `datetime`. And later you can get `date()`

```
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("2021.08.17", "%Y.%m.%d")

date = dt.date()

print(date)
```

---

**BTW:**

I see other problem in your example code. You try to get text from `Entry` directly after displaying `Entry`. But `Entry` doesn't work like `input()` - it doesn't wait for your changes - so you get text from `Entry` directly after displaying `Entry` - before you can change anything in `Entry`

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import datetime

def get_date():
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_w.get(), "%Y-%m-%d")
    date = dt.date()
    print(date)
    
def show_entry():
    global btn
    
    btn.destroy()

    date_input = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=date_w)
    date_input.pack()
    
    btn = tk.Button(root, text='Get Date', command=get_date)
    btn.pack()

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

date_w = tk.StringVar(root, value=datetime.date.today())

btn = tk.Button(root, text='Show Entry', comman=show_entry)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```